# sql raiserror specify parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameters

When i read the example of MSDN `raiserror`:

```
RAISERROR (N'This is message %s %d.', -- Message text.
           10, -- Severity,
           1, -- State,
           N'number', -- First argument.
           5); -- Second argument.
-- The message text returned is: This is message number 5.
GO
```

Why the doc using `%s` to specify the  `N'number'`,and  `%d` to specify the `5` -- Second argument

The MSDN write like this:

> For example, in the following RAISERROR statement, the first argument of N'number' replaces the first conversion specification of %s; and the second argument of 5 replaces the second conversion specification of %d.

My question is: How can explain it? Why don't using other like `%a` or `%b`.Any other `%+apha` can replace it.
I just want to get a meaningful understand.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This represents the parameter datatype.

```
+--------------------+----------------------+
| Type specification |      Represents      |
+--------------------+----------------------+
| d or i             | Signed integer       |
| o                  | Unsigned octal       |
| s                  | String               |
| u                  | Unsigned integer     |
| x or X             | Unsigned hexadecimal |
+--------------------+----------------------+
```

`N'number'` is an `nvarchar` string literal. So gets the `%s`specifier. And the literal `5` is a signed indicator so is represented by `%d`.

As for the reason for these specifiers. This is documented in the [`RAISERROR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) topic

> These type specifications are based on the ones originally defined for
>   the [printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) function in the C standard library